# Callback on Youtube Video is fully loaded

Tags: youtube-javascript-api

I was trying to develop an application where I would load a Youtube video, but I want to play it when it is fully available, however I could not find a proper callback in the [API Documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html) and on the [Demo Page](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/youtube_player_demo.html?playerType=embedded&playerVersion=as3).

However, on the Demo page, it updates the following:

```
Total bytes: 14316401
Start bytes: 0
Bytes loaded: 14316401
```

But, I do not know what is the best approach to that. Can you suggest me a proper and stable way of getting a callback when the video is fully loaded or fix me on if I am wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems no one cared, so I decided to go with checking the ratio(downloaded bytes/total bytes) in a 1/2 sec period.